# Do pages of ketuvim and navi'im need to be buried?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, navi-prophets, holy-objects, ketuvim, genizah-storage

Do books or sheets of paper that contain text from the Prophets (navi'im) and Writings (ketuvim) need to be discarded in a special manner?

I [know](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Burying_Religious_Articles#cite_note-1) that pages containing words of Torah written in any language need a "special" disposal--usually shaimos (burial). But does this include secondary parts of Torah too, or only Chumash?

(Since names of HaShem written in Hebrew always need geniza, let's assume the ketuvim in question are written in English.)

Comment: Yes, they need to be put in sheimos

Comment: @user3949142 That and a source makes an answer! [ btw, you _are_ allowed to change your name....unless you really really like the number 3949142 ;) ]

Comment: @Shokhet That's why I put it as a comment, I don't know the source. And I'm not sure how to change my name.

Comment: @user3949142 On your [user page](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/6886/user3949142), there is a button that says "edit" on it, across the top of the page (next to "privileges" "preferences" "flair" and "apps," if that helps you) .....click on it and you can edit your display name, which is the top option in that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not read the whole article yet (discovered through a comment on this site, it's on my 'to-read' list), but the cheat sheet found on page 15 of this [magazine](http://www.kosherspirit.com/pdfs/issue13.pdf) (Kosher Spirit Pesach 5768 [from the OK]) says that "A posuk of Tanach (if it was read)" must be put into *sheimos*.

Comment: "if it was read" How do you know it's there without reading it?

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair point....maybe someone printed nevi'im or kesuvim from the computer, and the pages came out of the printer face-down?

Comment: @DoubleAA Printing presses used to have a lot of copies of seforim that the printing went bad, so since no one read them, they were able to throw them out. Although I'm not sure if this is a heter b'dieved or even l'chatchila