# Hebrew names of G-d written in English letters

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, language, transliteration

I am referring to any of the [seven](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Geniza#Erasing_Hashem.27s_name) Hebrew names of Hashem that are forbidden to be erased. Suppose I have a sheet of paper that has one of them written, but in English letters ("Ad-noy").

1) Can the letters be erased?

2) Would the page need genizah/shaymos?

Please bring sources.

NOTE: My question differs from [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43441/transliterated-shemot) insofar as I really would like to know about *transliterated*, not translated, names of Hashem.
In the other case, the question was the same, but no one answered the correct question. (Everyone answered a question about *translated* names.) I am asking again in accordance with the following principle of duplication: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."

Comment: No, the question does not have an answer that actually answers it.

Comment: "Ad-nai" != "G-d"

Comment: if the answers don't address the question, or misunderstood it, you comment there, and or flag them as non-answers. You can also post a bounty to encourage quality answers.